# Optional only set in conditional compilation block, does compiler remove statement entirely from release build?

Tags: swift, assembly, build

For example:

```
struct L {
    #if DEBUG
    static let og:((String) -> Void)? = { print($0) }
    #else
    static let og:((String) -> Void)? = nil
    #endif
}
L.og?("Howdy!")
print("Done.")
```

In a release build of this code, what does the Swift compiler do with the line `L.og?("Howdy!")`? Does it optimize away the line completely? Or is the expression `L.og` evaluated to `nil` at run time? How do I prove either answer?

Comment: BTW you can avoid the optionality here by simply having a no-op closure, instead of `nil`.

Comment: @Alexander but in that case, I suspect the chances of the compiler optimizing the line would go down.

Comment: I think it will get in-lined in either case. The compiler does dead code elimination, and it should clean that up. In either case, I think that should be a secondary priortiy, with good API design should take precedence,  IMO.

Comment: @Alexander wrote "compiler does dead code elimination, and it should clean that up". My question is specifically about how to prove this. Thank you for trying to help, but this question is not about API design.

Comment: If I knew, I would have answered. Hence why I left a comment :)

Comment: @Alexander are you ready for a bit of delicious irony? Based on 2 days of experiments and second hand word from Joe Groff, I am reaching the conclusion that the complier cannot optimize away optionals but it can do so to an empty closure. So your suggestion will probably get me what I was after in the first place.

Comment: And that's the beauty of StackOverflow, and frame challenges in general.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have finally answered my own question. This edit entirely replaces my previous answer because I think it was wrong.

## Short answer

Compiler optimization does **not** remove the `L.og?("Howdy!")` line in `Release` builds. An unwrap of `og?` still happens at run time.

## Proof

### Define "Release"

In a typical Xcode project, what is the optimization for `Release`? In the target build settings it is `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -O`.

### Method

I ran `swiftc -emit-assembly -O` on 2 different programs.

Program A:

```
struct L {
    #if DEBUG
    static let og:((String) -> Void)? = { print($0) }
    #else
    static let og:((String) -> Void)? = nil
    #endif
}
L.og?("Howdy!")
```

Program B:

```
struct L {
    #if DEBUG
    static let og:((String) -> Void)? = { print($0) }
    #else
    static let og:((String) -> Void)? = nil
    #endif
}
```

In the assembly output, the `main` from *A*

```
_main:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %rax
    .cfi_offset %r13, -24
    cmpq    $-1, _globalinit_029_12232F587A4C5CD8B1EEDF696793B2FC_token0(%rip)
    jne LBB0_4
LBB0_1:
    movq    _$s4main1LV2ogySScSgvpZ(%rip), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  LBB0_3
    movq    _$s4main1LV2ogySScSgvpZ+8(%rip), %r13
    movabsq $36805260308296, %rdi
    movabsq $-1873497444986126336, %rsi
    callq   *%rax
LBB0_3:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %r13
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB0_4:
    leaq    _globalinit_029_12232F587A4C5CD8B1EEDF696793B2FC_token0(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    _globalinit_029_12232F587A4C5CD8B1EEDF696793B2FC_func0(%rip), %rsi
    callq   _swift_once
    jmp LBB0_1
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
```

And *B*:

```
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq

    .p2align    4, 0x90
```

If the compiler optimized away the entire line `L.og?("Howdy!")`, then I expect the `main` from *B* would be the same as *A*. It is not. Therefore, the complier leaves it in.

### Non-optional result

A similar result is found for non-optional empty closure instead. The call to `L.og("Howdy!")` remains in the optimized assembly even though the call is to an empty function.

That is:

```
struct L {
    #if DEBUG
    static let og:((String) -> Void) = { print($0) }
    #else
    static let og:((String) -> Void) = { _ in }
    #endif
}
L.og("Howdy!")
```

Here is optimized `main` assembly:

```
_main:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %rax
    .cfi_offset %r13, -24
    cmpq    $-1, _globalinit_029_12232F587A4C5CD8B1EEDF696793B2FC_token0(%rip)
    jne LBB0_1
LBB0_2:
    movq    _$s4main1LV2ogyySScvpZ+8(%rip), %r13
    movabsq $36805260308296, %rdi
    movabsq $-1873497444986126336, %rsi
    callq   *_$s4main1LV2ogyySScvpZ(%rip)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %r13
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB0_1:
    leaq    _globalinit_029_12232F587A4C5CD8B1EEDF696793B2FC_token0(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    _globalinit_029_12232F587A4C5CD8B1EEDF696793B2FC_func0(%rip), %rsi
    callq   _swift_once
    jmp LBB0_2
    .cfi_endproc

    .p2align    4, 0x90
```

Answer (score 1):

With conditional compilation, the compiler evaluates the state of the flag at build time.

Code inside an `#if` block that evaluates as true is compiled, and code that is inside an `#if` block that evaluates as false is ignored. (It is stripped away and will not appear in the binary.) In your case, for a release build, it would be as if your code was:

```
struct L {
    static let og:((String) -> Void)? = nil
}
L.og?("Howdy!")
print("Done.")
```

Thus, the "optional chaining" in the `L.og?("Howdy!")` would evaluate `L.og` as nil, and that code would never do anything.

I don't know the answer to the final part of your question, about whether or not the compiler completely optimizes away the line since it can never do anything. The LLVM compiler that builds Swift code is quite smart, and in release mode it might well strip the code away completely, but I'm not sure. You'd have to look at the assembly output to be sure.

Comment: except there's no guarantee that this is a debug build based on this `DEBUG` flag. In other words: since `DEBUG` flag has no special meaning for Swift, it can be present for release build (by mistake)

Comment: Thank you for responding, but what you have written is prerequisite knowledge to understanding my question. What the compiler does is not the "final part" of my question it is the main question as I have written in the title.

Comment: I realized that as I was finishing my "answer." I guess in hindsight it would be better as a comment, but the lack of formatting on comments would make it hard to read.